# The product's required option(s) weren't entered. Make sure the options are entered and try again

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.1

I am getting the standard error when the product requires options to be selected before adding to the quote/cart. However, it seems the error is displaying multiple times to match the number of options there are. See screenshot below.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is asterisk/star symbol present at

1. Please specify length(mm)*
2. Please specify width (mm) - Minimum width 50mm*
3. Please specify depth(mm)* 
   So, you must have to provide all these details, they are not optional , they are compulsory fields and you must have to fill them.

   Try to fill these details then submit, it should accept your entry. 
   **Edited and added more details**
   A sublime screenshot is added you need to select the file according to your module and do tracing backtract to resolve this error ..
   [image]
   Thanks
   Vibhore

Comment: I should have been more specific. I understand what is required on the front end. I am needing the error to display only once despite how many *required fields there are. I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Seems like this is work of some foreach loop that keep on concatenate the error message again and again.In your sublime, where you installed application go to m241 folder(root of magento), we need to find the string in all the file together, then press ctrl+shift+F  (find shortcut) in Where: type `/var/www/html/development_m241/m241`  and Find: entered. Make sure the options are entered and try again.    then press enter.. it will search in around 70thousand files  and tell you where exactly this file is located in backend. you can stop the string concatenation there.